# How to use integratedTerminal in launch.json for C++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, configuration, visual-studio-code

I am trying Visual Studio Code for debugging C++ code. I would like the debugger to use the integrated terminal for showing the STDOUT and reading from the STDIN. Currently it opens an external terminal.

I tried putting `"console": "integratedTerminal"` in launch.json but I get the parsing error: `Property console is not allowed`.

How can I achieve the behaviour I described?

EDIT: this is my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path_to_my_executable",            
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
}
```

Comment: Should work! Pls. show your whole launch.json. Should look like this: `{"configuration": [{ "console": "integratedTerminal", .... }]}`

Comment: @jps I updated my answer with my configuration file

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time to test this today. I deleted my answer and hope someone else knows. Btw. which C++ Compiler do you use?

Comment: Don't worry, clang++

Answer (score 0):

the default setting for STDOUT and STDIN of c++ is just the "integratedTerminal" or "integratedConsole".

> you can change it by enabling **"externalConsole":true** in the launch.json then you will get a pop up console window that you can type in.

also if you encounter the same problem as me that the integratedTerminal cannot read input from user as below hanging(env. windows 10)
[image]

> my solution was to replace cygwin's gdb and g ++ with **mingw64**'s.

then the input output are normal
[image]